# How to get text input to display text in Flash Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

It's been forever since I've done Actionscript and we have a really old one that had to be redone in Actionscript 3.
It has a textinput for a search and a "search" button that will call a webpage when pressed.
My problem is that when I run it, I can enter text into the textinput but you don't see anything that you typed and I can't figure why. I've got the script to get the textinput as a variable and it goes to the test page, but I need to make the text visible in the SWF.

Here's my Actionscript:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import fl.controls.Label; 
import fl.controls.TextInput; 

var searchtext = misa_stext.text;
gosearch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick);
function onMouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   var searchtext = misa_stext.text;
   var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://stackoverflow.com?" + searchtext);
   request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
   var target:String = "_blank";
   navigateToURL(request, target);
}
```

It does what it's supposed to do, I just want the user to see what they typed and I know I'm missing something.

UPDATE:
Here's what the properties panel says:

[image]

And what I get when embedding:
[image]

But still nothing. :(

Comment: Most likely your text field is not set for `embedFonts=true` and uses an embedded font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input does not use system fonts, you must embed the font to support dynamic text.

Press *Embed...* from the text input properties

[image: font-properties]

Then include character ranges as needed.

[image]

Comment: I added screen shots of my screen to show what I see and still no text. Could it be my font itself?

Comment: Nevermind; When in doubt, restart. I restarted and it works now. Thanks!